# How to expire a Cookie using Jquery at midnight?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I did this:

```
$.cookie("ultOS", (i), {expires:1});
```

But it will only expire next day.

How can I expire a cookie at midnight?

Would this work instead?

```
var date = new Date();
var midnight = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);
$.cookie("ultOS", (i), {expires: midnight});
```

Comment: this is very smart! I was going to use date.getDate()+1 just like was answered below but was concerned because end of the month. Your midnight is the perfect midnight!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
expirationDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate()+1, 0, 0, 0);
$.cookie("ultOS", "5", {expires: expirationDate});
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the latest version of ths cookie plugin (assuming this is the one you're using: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie), you can pass a normal Date object in.

I haven't tried it, but the source of the plugin is fairly straightforward....

```
if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == 'number' || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
            var date;
            if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
                date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            } else {
                date = options.expires;
            }
            expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString(); // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
        }
```

If you pass in a number, it assumes that's number of days.  If you pass in a Date, it takes that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date();
var midnight = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);
var expires = "expires="+midnight.toGMTString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Javascript Date object with tonights (midnight) value, then set the expiration as follows:

```
 $.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });
```

Where date is the date object.