# Code Javascript for a cookie that expires at midnight

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a pop-up with a cookie that expires in one day (24 hours) and I would like that this cookie expires at midnight everyday (so the pop-up shows the first time you enter to the web every day). I'm not a programmer, so, please, could someone tell me what I have to change in my code? I have read some solutions to my question, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($.cookie("anewsletter") != 1) { 
//centering with css
centerPopup();
//load popup
loadPopup(); 
}     
//CLOSING POPUP
//Click the x event!
$("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
disablePopup();
$.cookie("anewsletter", "1", { expires: 1 });
});

//Click the bacground!
$("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
disablePopup();
$.cookie("anewsletter", "1", { expires: 1 });
});


//Press Escape event!
$(document).keypress(function(e){
if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
    disablePopup();
    $.cookie("anewsletter", "1", { expires: 1 });
}
});

});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expire a Cookie using Jquery at midnight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627821/how-to-expire-a-cookie-using-jquery-at-midnight)

Answer (score 10):

`$.cookie` can take a date as `expires` value, so you can use the following

```
var midnight = new Date();
midnight.setHours(23,59,59,0);

$.cookie('anewsletter', '1', { expires: midnight });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok - this will either create a cookie when a visitor first comes - that cookie will expire at 23:59:59 (the second before midnite), so if they visit from midnight or later, then it will redo the cookie.  You could add your conditional code in the if visited == 0 section (where it sets the cookie) - this would only run if the cookie does not exists (or has expired).

```
var visited = 0;
function cookieTest() {
    if (visited == 0) {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setHours(23);
        exdate.setMinutes(59);
        exdate.setSeconds(59);
        document.cookie='visited=1; expires='+exdate+'; path=/';
    }
    else {
        alert("you've been here before!");
    }
}
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) visited = ( c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length));
    }
    return null;
}
readCookie('visited');
cookieTest();
```

And [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AkyGT/1/).